# How to substitute a string in list from other lists where there is a match

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Assume I have two source directories:

- srcdir0 - Contains source files for generation 0 compile
- srcdir1 - Contains subset of srcdir0 files

I create file list for `srcdir0` and `srcdir1`

```
S0SRCS := $(wildcard $(srcdir0)/*.c)
S1SRCS := $(wildcard $(srcdir1)/*.c)
```

I'm trying to create a final list that has the base `srcdir0` files but are substituted by `srcdir1` files of the same name. In other words the `srcdir1` files take precedence.

I'm thinking that the `filter` or `filter-out` functions may be my friend here but I'm not experienced enough to know better.

Comment: This might be an XY problem. Do you actually need that list, or do you just want Make to prioritise the source files that way? -- in which case vpath will do it very neatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it suffices to filter out the names from the `S1` directory from the names of the `S0`:

```
S0NAMES := $(notdir $(S0SRCS))
S1NAMES := $(notdir $(S1SRCS))
FINAL-LIST := $(addprefix $(srcdir0)/,$(filter-out $(S1NAMES),$(S0NAMES))) $(S1SRCS)
```

Please test this first, I didn't have the opportunity to do so and wrote it just off the top of my head.

Comment: Blindfolded bullseye. +1.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out today.

Comment: Works like a charm: Answer +1